# Struts2 anchor tag doesn't include contextPath

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, contextpath

`%{#request.contextPath}` doesn't work inside an s:a tag in Struts2. (Struts 2.2.1 to be specific.)  Is there a way to make it work? It works in other Struts2 tags.

Here are two lines in a JSP file in a Struts 2 project whose context path is "/websites":

```
<s:a href="%{#request.contextPath}/clickme" theme="simple">Click here.</s:a>
<s:form method="post" action="%{#request.contextPath}/submitme" theme="simple"></s:form>
```

And here is the output:

```
<a href="/clickme">Click here.</a>
<form id="submitme" name="submitme" action="/websites/submitme" method="post"></form>
```

Notice that the context path is left off the anchor but is included in the form.

P.S. I can't use `${#pageContext.request.contextPath}` here because `${}` isn't allowed in Struts2 tags. Besides, I'm trying to be consistent.  And I also try generally to avoid `${}` since it does not auto-escape the output.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't do Struts2, but I took a quick glance in their docs, isn't the [`s:url`](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/url.html) what you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
<s:set id="contextPath"  value="#request.get('javax.servlet.forward.context_path')" />
<s:a href="%{contextPath}/clickme" theme="simple">Click here.</s:a>
```

However, you're not supposed to do this. When you need an url, use the `<s:url>` tag:

```
<%-- Without specifying an action --%>
<s:url id="myUrl" value="clickme" />
<s:a href="%{myUrl}" theme="simple">Click here.</s:a>

<%-- With an action --%>
<s:url id="myUrl" action="clickme" />
<s:a href="%{myUrl}" theme="simple">Click here.</s:a>
```

By the way, you don't need a context path for the action attribute of a form:

```
<s:form method="post" action="submitme" theme="simple"></s:form>
```

Comment: Thanks. I had tried `<s:set id="contextPath" value="#request.contextPath" />` without success but hadn't tried your version. But in the end I used `<s:url />` like this: `<a href="<s:url value="clickme" />"Click here</a>` Also used a global setting to set the `includeParams` attribute to "none" by default.

Answer (score 1):

Does Struts 2 support `EL`?

You can use `${request.contextPath}` if it does....

Comment: Struts tags use OGNL expressions

Comment: AAah, ok...JSP 2.0 supports EL, so the OP can use it with his Struts 2 tag (or can't it?). I clearly remember using EL with Struts 1.3.6 and higher....

Comment: I mentioned in the P.S. part of the question that I can't use the `${}` syntax in a Struts 2 tag and that I tend to avoid it because it doesn't auto-escape the output.

Comment: Your PS probably came later (after I wrote this). I'll try and see if Struts 2 support `EL` under JSP 2.0 and higher.